# How to add dashed lines between elements of a list?

Tags: r

I have a list like this:

```
x <- 1
y <- 2
z <- "something"
my_list <- list("x" = x, "y" = y, "z" = z)
> my_list
$x
[1] 1
$y
[1] 2
$z
"something"
```

in truth my list is very long including big text elements such that in output I can not recognise them easily. Therefore I want to put a dashed line after every element of the list in Output like

```
$x
[1] 1
-------------------------------------
$y
[1] 2
-------------------------------------
$z
[1] "something"
-------------------------------------
```

Comment: You can see the print method for lists by typing `print.list` in your concole. If you want to modify the print behavior, you can make your own version of `print.list`.

Comment: Is this for printing

Comment: @ arkun Yes! this is for printing

Comment: @Hector Haffenden that is a great idea thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this could work.

```
mylistprint <- function(x){

    nn <- names(x)
    ll <- length(x)
    if (length(nn) != ll) {
      nn <- paste("Component", seq.int(ll))
      }
    for (i in seq_len(ll)) {
      cat(nn[i], ":\n")
      print(x[[i]])
      cat("\n")
      cat(strrep("-", 25))
      cat("\n")
    }
    invisible(x)
}

mylistprint(my_list)
```

The output of this would be:

```
x :
[1] 1

-------------------------
y :
[1] 2

-------------------------
z :
[1] "something"

-------------------------
```

Comment: Good option. One improvement might be `strrep("-", 25)` instead of `paste0(rep("-", 25),collapse = "" )`

Comment: I have added `strrep("-", 25)` in place of `paste0(rep("-", 25),collapse = "" )`, which is a great improvement.

Answer (score 3):

**Using mapply** 
Probably a nicer way to do this is using `mapply`, or at least it is much shorter.

```
fun1 <- function(x,y) cat(paste0('$', x), y,strrep("-", 25), sep = '\n')
x <- mapply(fun1, names(my_list), my_list)
```

This prints:

```
$x
1
-------------------------
$y
2
-------------------------
$z
something
-------------------------
```

**Single line**

```
x <- mapply(function(x,y) cat(paste0('$', x), y,strrep("-", 25), sep = '\n'), names(my_list), my_list)
```

**Wrap it in a function if you want**

```
print.list <- function(list) {
  x <- mapply(function(x,y) cat(paste0('$', x), y,strrep("-", 25), sep = '\n'), names(list), list)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From my comments, you could run a for loop, printing each element of a list, then printing `"--------...-----"`, then the next element of a list, put this into a function and you are done, for example,

```
lsprint <- function(list){
  for (i in 1:length(list)){
    print(names(my_list)[i])
    print(my_list[[i]])
    print('--------------------')
  }

}
lsprint(my_list)
```

Returns,

```
[1] "x"
[1] 1
[1] "--------------------"
[1] "y"
[1] 2
[1] "--------------------"
[1] "z"
[1] "something"
[1] "--------------------"
```

Edit: Added so you get the name

Comment: This does not show the original names of the list items, like `$x` which may be inconvenient  if you need to find something. @markus answer had this unfortunately he deleted it